# How do I automatically generate pages from a database?

Tags: plugins, automation

I have a spreadsheet of information I'd like to publish online. I'm trying to find the easiest and best-looking way of doing this. The page will be informational and not intended to generate revenue so I'm hoping to be able to do this cheaply - WordPress seems like the best option.

I'd like to create a website to display my data in different ways. For example, one page would tabulate most of the data. From there, you could click on a heading and go to a page just for that entry, with additional information. Another page would tabulate data only relevant to that day. And so on.

It's not really a blog-style page. Is there a good way of doing this with WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a more general question, so I'll offer some general comments.

There are WordPress plugins such as TablePress (https://tablepress.org) that do a nice job displaying data on a WordPress page.  The individual data points can be made linkable to another page, as needed.

This is, likely, a custom solution, meaning, a developer could help you structure custom data fields and presentation tables.

I haven't tested, but the quickest way (maybe, not ideal) would be to post a pdf of the table on a WordPress page, perhaps, with some cells linked to other site pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use WordPress native posts or CPT , you can achieve this with programmatically which will be the fastest way to do. Where via code using CSV library you fetch records from Excel and using wp_insert_post function you add those posts to WordPress via a loop with meta data etc...

Or if you want to avoid custom coding route, there is a plugin called wp all import or wp all export or both , free and paid options that we have used once to import excel spreadsheet CSV data into wp posts.

Plugin I mentioned above is: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/